# Is there an OOP principle against a concrete class extending another concrete class?

Tags: oop

I have read that this should be avoided, though I can't recall the source. Inheritance should used with abstract classes in the middle of the hierarchy, and concrete classes showing only as leaves.

Where can I find a good explanation of the reasoning behind this? (Opposite opinions are also welcome)

Comment: Can you please point to the source that says this should be avoided?

Comment: @Oded - that's what I'm trying to find out. I read it somewhere, and the arguments did convince me, only it was some time ago and I don't remember.

Comment: Fair enough - however, you state this as a "known" thing. I have not heard of a principle in OOP that states that inheriting form concrete classes is bad practice. If you question is about the validity of this assertion, that's what you should be asking about and not for reasoning that support this assertion.

Comment: @Oded - rephrased the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be taken too strictly.
I think the underlying idea is more to focus on programming to an interface, either a pure interface or an abstract class, as this enables looser coupling of your design, polymorphism, encapsulation,...

Also mind to not violate the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)